# How to solve JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char0) in google sheets api?

Tags: python, json, api, google-sheets

I want to get some data from google sheets api like this

```
import httplib2
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

import json


CREED_FILE = 'creed2.json'
spreadsheet_id = 'XXX'

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    CREED_FILE, 
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
)
httpAuth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = build('sheets', 'v4', http = httpAuth)

def get():
    try:
        values = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
            spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
            range='Sheet1!A1:E8',
            majorDimension='ROWS'
        )
        return values
    except HttpError as err:
        e = json.loads(err.content.decode('utf-8'))

get().execute()
```

After executing this code i got an JSONDecodeError: Expecting value line 1 column 1 (char 0).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g_sheets.py", line 78, in <module>
    get().execute()
  File "E:\Python_projects\Flask_exmpl\hookt\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Python_projects\Flask_exmpl\hookt\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 923, in execute
    resp, content = _retry_request(
  File "E:\Python_projects\Flask_exmpl\hookt\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 191, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Python_projects\Flask_exmpl\hookt\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\transport.py", line 159, in new_request
    credentials._refresh(orig_request_method)
  File "E:\Python_projects\Flask_exmpl\hookt\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 749, in _refresh
    self._do_refresh_request(http)
  File "E:\Python_projects\Flask_exmpl\hookt\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 783, in _do_refresh_request
    d = json.loads(content)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

As far as I know this error can occur when we want to parse a site with a 404 response.
But how to fix this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _But how to fix this?_ Verify that the request was successful before you call `.json()`.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, I've already figured it out. The problem was banal and simple. I had to write not like this

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
CREED_FILE, 
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
```

)

but like this

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
CREED_FILE, 
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
```

)

And everything will be work.)